# 'NIOTSConnectionBootstrap' is only available in watchOS 6.0 or newer

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos

I'm developing a watchOS app with a companion iOS app and running to an issue with the package i'm using that.

The app doesn't build with:

`'NIOTSConnectionBootstrap' is only available in watchOS 6.0 or newer`

while I'm deploying on watchOS 9.0

I tried changing the deployment target from 9.1 to 9.0 down to 7.0, for watchOS, but nothing worked.